# Define Qt Layout so that it keeps minimum size

Tags: layout, widget, qt6, qsizepolicy

I would like a Qt dialog to have the minimum size possible given the layout.

The layout consists of a QVBoxDialog, with several elements. One is a QLabel with a QPixmap. This is the fixed size element that I would like to constrain the QDialog's width.

The problem now is that it remains possible to enlarge the QDialog, which then leaves a blank space to the side of the QLabel.

How can I achieve that the layout of the widget (the QDialog) cannot be enlarged by "adding empty space" to the right of the QLabel?

Here is a MWE illustrating the problem:

File main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>

class Dialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Dialog();
    ~Dialog() {};
private:
    QLabel *px;
    QPixmap pxmap;
};


#endif // MAIN_H
```

File main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QColor>
#include <QSizePolicy>

#include "main.h"

Dialog::Dialog() {
    setWindowTitle("MWE");

    resize(100,100);

    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    setLayout(vLayout);

    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    vLayout->addLayout(hLayout);

    QPushButton * btn;
    hLayout->addWidget(btn = new QPushButton("AA"));
    btn->setMinimumWidth(10);
    hLayout->addWidget(btn = new QPushButton("BB"));
    btn->setMinimumWidth(10);
    hLayout->addWidget(btn = new QPushButton("CC"));
    btn->setMinimumWidth(10);

    vLayout->addWidget(px = new QLabel());

    pxmap = QPixmap(QSize(150, 150));
    pxmap.fill((QColor("red")));
    px->setPixmap(pxmap);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

What I would like is this minimum size:

[image]

...and I would like to prevent the dialog from being enlarged like below (the green arrows indicate the added space):

[image]

I tried setting different `QSizePolicy`s to the dialog and the layout, but without success.

Comment: "*I would like a Qt dialog to have the minimum size possible given the layout.*". Maybe `setFixedSize(layout()->minimumSize());` is what you need?

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub Yes, this works! But I guess it means that it is not a dynamic property of the layout, i.e. if a layout component changes, then the widget might be too small or too large.

Comment: If I understand correctly, try to just reset the fixed size after the changes occur. The results would help even of it doesn't work. It also would help to provide such an example where the label would change its size somehow, to clarify exactly your use case and constraints.